# Why is it vulnerable to bind docker daemon to 0.0.0.0?

Tags: security, docker, continuous-integration, port

Recently I was getting an error in my docker gitlab CI container:

Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?

I found this thread where [one post suggests](https://forums.docker.com/t/cannot-connect-to-the-docker-daemon-is-the-docker-daemon-running-on-this-host/8925/4):

`sudo service docker stop && sudo nohup docker daemon -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375 -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock &`

Eventually I got an abuse warning at my server host that my box was port scanning all over port 2375

I found an instance of https://hub.docker.com/r/kannix/monero-miner/
killed it ten times and eventually rebooted, and it has not returned since.

[This site](https://www.speedguide.net/port.php?port=2375) indicates there is a:

> A vulnerability in the Docker Engine configuration of Cisco
>   CloudCenter Orchestrator (CCO; formerly CliQr) could allow an
>   unauthenticated, remote attacker to install Docker containers with
>   high privileges on the affected system. Affected Products: This
>   vulnerability affect all releases of Cisco CloudCenter Orchestrator
>   (CCO) deployments where the Docker Engine TCP port 2375 is open on the
>   system and bound to local address 0.0.0.0 (any interface).

So my question is: Is the above way (binding to tcp://0.0.0.0:2375) to start docker daemon vulnerable inherently (and if so, why?) or is it a bug in docker?

Answer (score 3):

"Any interface" means that you want the docker daemon to listen to incoming connections on *all* network interfaces, as opposed to just localhost.  This mean that anybody who can reach the server, can connect to port 2375 and reach the Docker daemon and exploit it.  "High privileges" is "root", so your system is compromised and should be reinstalled from scratch.

The easy way around this is to say that you should only be able to connect to the docker daemon from trusted hosts, which in turn mean selecting what network interfaces to bind to.  A typical choice is "localhost" as this allows only connections from the machine itself.

Comment: OK! So it seems that the comment in that post is dangerous and misleading! I would tend to report it - Do you agree?

Comment: If you mess with things like this you _ought_ to know what you are talking about. If you correct others, even more so. I would suggest you seek more insight and then decide for yourself.